# stringr for extracting patterns

Tags: r, stringr

I am using R to solve the problem

```
states = c("Masassachusetts, USA", "Buffalo, NY", "Flint, MI","California, USA", "Idaho, USA", "Orlando, FL"...)
```

I need to get a new vector which would be like

```
state_name = (Massachusetts, NY, MI, California, Idaho, FL..)
```

I tried to do pattern match by using `stringr` but unable to figure out how to print the state name or abbreviation

```
ifelse(str_detect(states," [A-Z][A-Z]")),#need to figure out what to do write to get the abbreviated state
 ifelse(str_deteCt(states,"[U][S][A]))#  code to print the full name state
,other))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
library(stringr)
```

The separator is given as "\, " instead of "\,", assuming that the strings have a space after the comma (leading white space before USA).

```
state_name <- ifelse(word(states,2,sep = "\\, ")=="USA", word(states,1,sep = "\\,"), 
                 word(states,2,sep = "\\, "))
```

This above code will not be robust, when there is not white space before USA. In such case, it will print "USA". The code given below will work, when there is a mix of strings with white space and without white space.

```
state_name <- ifelse(word(states, -1) =="USA", word(states,1,sep = "\\,"), 
                     word(states,2,sep = "\\, "))
```

Note that the the separator for the third function is still ""\, " considering the leading white space. You can also have it as "\," instead and remove the white space from the output later.

```
state_name <- ifelse(word(states, -1) =="USA", word(states,1,sep = "\\,"), 
                     word(states,2,sep = "\\,"))

state_name <- trimws(state_name, which = "l")

state_name
#[1] "Masassachusetts" "NY"              "MI"              "California"      "Idaho"           "FL"
```

**Edit:**
To answer the question in the comment about having NA, when dataset is like:

```
states <- c("Masassachusetts, USA", "SUNNY Buffalo" 
           "Buffalo, NY", "Flint, MI","California, USA", 
           "Idaho, USA", "Orlando, FL", "Shanghai, China")
```

In this scenario, my suggestion is to have list of names of the states and their abbreviations (attached attach end of the answer).

`%in%` can be used to confirm if the strings are names of the states.

```
library(dplyr)

state_name <- ifelse(word(states, -1) =="USA", word(states,1,sep = "\\,"),
                     ifelse(word(states, 2, sep = "\\, ") %in% stl, 
                            word(states, 2, sep = "\\, "), NA))

state_name
#[1] "Masassachusetts" NA                "NY"              "MI"              "California"      "Idaho"          
#[7] "FL"              NA
```

List of the state names and their abbreviations:

```
stl <- c("Alabama", "Alaska", "Arizona", "Arkansas", "California", "Colorado", 
         "Connecticut", "Delaware", "Florida", "Georgia", "Hawaii", "Idaho", 
         "Illinois", "Indiana", "Iowa", "Kansas", "Kentucky", "Louisiana", 
         "Maine", "Maryland", "Massachusetts", "Michigan", "Minnesota", 
         "Mississippi", "Missouri", "Montana", "Nebraska", "Nevada", "New Hampshire", 
         "New Jersey", "New Mexico", "New York", "North Carolina", "North Dakota", 
         "Ohio", "Oklahoma", "Oregon", "Pennsylvania", "Rhode Island", 
         "South Carolina", "South Dakota", "Tennessee", "Texas", "Utah", 
         "Vermont", "Virginia", "Washington", "West Virginia", "Wisconsin", 
         "Wyoming", "AL", "AK", "AZ", "AR", "CA", "CO", "CT", "DE", "FL", 
         "GA", "HI", "ID", "IL", "IN", "IA", "KS", "KY", "LA", "ME", "MD", 
         "MA", "MI", "MN", "MS", "MO", "MT", "NE", "NV", "NH", "NJ", "NM", 
         "NY", "NC", "ND", "OH", "OK", "OR", "PA", "RI", "SC", "SD", "TN", 
         "TX", "UT", "VT", "VA", "WA", "WV", "WI", "WY")
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. Just wish to know the code. If I remove the space  between "\\, " in word(states,2,sep = "\\, ")=="USA" and word(states,2,sep = "\\, ") Only USA is printed for the states name. Can you please explain why?  Secondly if I wish to put a "exception"  or "NA" for those entries which do not meet the both criteria.

Comment: @Tania I have updated my answer. I hope it answers your question. With respect to having the NA, I have included one condition in the code and the result is based on whether it meets it or not. can you update the sample with the strings having the third criteria, so that I can refine my answer.

Comment: I truly appreciate how you explained the code. I learnt two more function word and trimws. My data has whitespace after "/, ". But thanks for explaining all the scenarios. If my dataset is like states = c("Masassachusetts, USA", "SUNNY Buffalo" "Buffalo, NY", "Flint, MI","California, USA", "Idaho, USA", "Orlando, FL", "Shanghai, China"). I wish to put "NA" in cases where it is SUNY Buffalo or China.

Comment: @Tania Check my edit. This will work, if the state names have the traditional abbreviation like Ala., Calif., etc., you can add those to stl.

Comment: I was also tryingto play around the code. I created another vector defining whether the state entry is full name or state abbrev or other.  states <- c("Masassachusetts, USA", "SUNNY Buffalo" 
           "Buffalo, NY", "Flint, MI","California, USA", 
           "Idaho, USA", "Orlando, FL", "Shanghai, China") states <- c("Masassachusetts, USA", "SUNNY Buffalo" 
           "Buffalo, NY", "Flint, MI","California, USA", 
           "Idaho, USA", "Orlando, FL", "Shanghai, China")

Comment: I was trying to explore the code. I created a dataframe with states and type(which explains the type of location the states explains. states <- c("Masassachusetts, USA", "SUNNY Buffalo", "Buffalo, NY", "Flint, MI","California, USA", "Idaho, USA", "Orlando, FL", "Shanghai, China")
type = c("state", "other", "state abb", "state abb","state", "state", "state abb", "other")
Statesdf <- data.frame(states,type)

Comment: sorry I couldn't complete in my comment Statesdf %>% mutate(new = ifelse(type == "state", word(states,1,"\\,"), ifelse(type == "state abb", word(states,2,sep = "\\, "), "NA"))). Its throwing me an error Error in end[neg_end] + len[neg_end] : non-numeric argument to binary operator. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The first word() function is missing sep = . Apart from this your code is perfect. Awesome!